# How to cross validate a Naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: r, classification, naivebayes

I use e1071 for naive classification

function

```
naiveBayes(x=, y=, )
```

I want to use cvTools for cross-validation

```
cvFit(....)
```

how could I write this, the documentation of cvFit is really hard to understand for me

```
typeof(naiveBayes) is 'closure'
```

Comment: Is there any better approach to this issue? A couple of years have already passed...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is much better to start using **caret** package. e.g. here's part of the code I am currently working on:

```
    library('caret')

    train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)

    #create model
    fit <- train(trainData[, -classIndex], trainData[, classIndex], method = "nb",trControl=train_control)
```

Comment: That uses the klaR package, which in my experience is insanely slow for naive bayes.  It took 100-1000x longer than e1071 in R or sklearn in Python.